# Javascript refactor oftenly called function

Tags: refactoring, dry, javascript

I'm working with javascript for quite a long time, but it happens to me often that I come up with the following code:

```
function1 () {
  // do stuff
  ...
  end_function();
}

function2 () {
  // do stuff
  ...
  end_function();
}

function3 () {
  // do stuff
  ...
  end_function();
}
```

I know this is in conflict with the DRY principles, but unfortunately, I don't know what to do with it to remove the repetitions. Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: You should post this to codereview.stackexchange.com and with the actual code included.

Comment: Thank you, I will do this if no one answers here, though SO in my opinion is way more popular than codereview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be in conflict with DRY if you code the `end_function` directly into the other functions. Ultimately you do need *some* syntax to invoke the code that you abstracted into its own function.

If functions are grouped together into an Object, I suppose you could enumerate the properties of the object, and wrap each function, but that's probably only worth it you have many of these functions.

```
var funcs = {
    function1 () {
      // do stuff
    },
    function2 () {
      // do stuff
    },
    function3 () {
      // do stuff
    }
};
```

---

```
Object.keys(funcs).forEach(function(key) {
    var orig = funcs[key];
    funcs[key] = function() {
        orig.apply(this, arguments);
        end_function();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is so many solutions.

One way is wrap function like "am not i am's" answer,

another is use higher-order function.

```
var end_function = function(callback){

    callback.call();

    // do some stuff 
};

var stuff1 = function(){};
var stuff2 = function(){}:

end_function(stuff1);
end_function(stuff2);
```